# Как записать dhparams по роботу Kuka kr20 в Matlab

Tags: matlab

Опыта работы в Matlab и робототехнике не имею. Пыталась разобраться по примерам и учебникам. [Характеристики робота, технические данные](https://www.kuka.com/-/media/kuka-downloads/imported/8350ff3ca11642998dbdc81dcc2ed44c/0000283881_en.pdf?rev=cd015f3edc724505a776793ee44e90a2&hash=4F900657D8CB590C770C6F1C28C2D636). Посмотрите, если есть ошибки укажите в чем причина.

```
 dhparams = [0                0.975     0.26      (-pi/2);
             0                0         0.680     0      ;
             (-pi/2)          0        -0.035     (-pi/2);
             0                0.670     0         pi/2   ;
             0                0         0         (-pi/2);
             0                0.115     0         0      ];
```

Начальное положение суставов робота по задаче:

```
     A1=-33.8969193
     A2=-78.9970322
     A3=98.2957916
     A4=304.597107
     A5=18.9458447
     A6=-56.7847748
     E1=-7.09412794E-15
     E2=41895.7656
     E3=0.0
     E4=0.0
     E5=0.0
     E6=0.0
```